# How to find the 3rd Wednesday of the month in XSLT 1.0

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

I have to find the next 3rd Wednesday of a month and I can't seem to come up with a good solution on XSLT to do this. For instance, today is August 11th so the next 3rd Wednesday of the month is August 16th. But if today is August 17th then the next 3rd Wednesday of the month will be Sept 20th.

Is there anyway to do this in XSLT 1.0?

Comment: Are you actually working on an input XML file?  Or is this a purely academic exercise in mathematics?

Comment: There's an input XML file that contains today's date

Comment: @S.Menon Calculating the 3rd Wednesday of *this* month is complicated enough (as you can see from my answer below). If you need the *next* 3rd Wednesday in *any* month, you will need to (a) find the 3rd Wednesday of *this* month, (b) compare it to the given date, and if necessary (c) find  the 3rd Wednesday of *next* month.

Answer (score 3):

Interesting problem - let's make it more generic:

### Calculating N-th day-of-week in a given month, using pure XSLT 1.0:

```
<xsl:template name="Nth-weekday-of-month">
    <xsl:param name="year"/>
    <xsl:param name="month"/><!-- 1..12 = Jan..Dec -->
    <xsl:param name="weekday"/><!-- 0..6 = Sun..Sat -->
    <xsl:param name="N"/>
    <!-- month starts on ... -->
    <xsl:variable name="first-of-month">
        <xsl:call-template name="JDN">
            <xsl:with-param name="year" select="$year" />
            <xsl:with-param name="month" select="$month" />
            <xsl:with-param name="day" select="1" />
        </xsl:call-template>
    </xsl:variable>
    <!-- ... day of week -->
    <xsl:variable name="dow-first-of-month" select="($first-of-month + 1) mod 7"/>
    <!-- distance to next day-of-week -->
    <xsl:variable name="diff" select="(7 + $weekday - $dow-first-of-month) mod 7"/>
    <!-- next day-of-week -->
        <xsl:call-template name="GD">
            <xsl:with-param name="JDN" select="$first-of-month + $diff + 7*($N - 1)" />
        </xsl:call-template>
</xsl:template> 

<xsl:template name="JDN">
    <xsl:param name="year"/>
    <xsl:param name="month"/>
    <xsl:param name="day"/>
    <!-- calculate JDN  -->
    <xsl:variable name="a" select="floor((14 - $month) div 12)"/>
    <xsl:variable name="y" select="$year + 4800 - $a"/>
    <xsl:variable name="m" select="$month + 12*$a - 3"/>
    <xsl:value-of select="$day + floor((153*$m + 2) div 5) + 365*$y + floor($y div 4) - floor($y div 100) + floor($y div 400) - 32045" />
</xsl:template> 

<xsl:template name="GD">
    <xsl:param name="JDN"/>
    <xsl:variable name="f" select="$JDN + 1401 + floor((floor((4 * $JDN + 274277) div 146097) * 3) div 4) - 38"/>
    <xsl:variable name="e" select="4*$f + 3"/>
    <xsl:variable name="g" select="floor(($e mod 1461) div 4)"/>
    <xsl:variable name="h" select="5*$g + 2"/>
    <xsl:variable name="D" select="floor(($h mod 153) div 5 ) + 1"/>
    <xsl:variable name="M" select="(floor($h div 153) + 2) mod 12 + 1"/>
    <xsl:variable name="Y" select="floor($e div 1461) - 4716 + floor((14 - $M) div 12)"/>

    <xsl:value-of select="$Y" />    
    <xsl:value-of select="format-number($M, '-00')"/>
    <xsl:value-of select="format-number($D, '-00')"/>
</xsl:template>
```

---

Example of call:

```
<xsl:call-template name="Nth-weekday-of-month">
    <xsl:with-param name="year" select="2017" />
    <xsl:with-param name="month" select="8" />
    <xsl:with-param name="weekday" select="3" />
    <xsl:with-param name="N" select="3" />
</xsl:call-template>
```

returns `2017-08-16`, the date of the 3rd Wednesday in August 2017.

---

Demo showing calculation of the 3rd Wednesday in every month in the years 2014-2017: http://xsltransform.net/a9Gixf/1