# how to know week day using xslt 1.0

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0

I have 2 requirements.

lets take an example date.

`<date>20190320</date>`

I want to know

1)Which week day is 20th March 2019. In this case output should be Wednesday.

2)I also want to know if it is Wednesday then whether it is 3rd Wednesday of the month. In our case output should be 'yes'. 20th march is 3rd Wednesday of the march month.

Thanks

Comment: What did you try? Which error did you get? Write a [mcve].

Comment: Please ask one question at a time. You will find the answer to your second question here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45640923/3016153

Comment: note you will have to do some work to make the linked answer work, as it expects the date formats to be - separated. Ask a new question referring to the answer linked above and ask ask how to make it work with non-hyphenated date formats.

Comment: @user254694 Extracting the date elements from `YYYYMMDD` is just as trivial as working with `YYYY-MM-DD`. To get the month, you only need to adjust `substring($date, 6, 2)` to `substring($date, 5, 2)` and so on.

Comment: @michael.hor257k sure, it is trivial, but the need does differ slightly from the code given, if he can't make the code given work he should ask a new question about what needs to be changed in the code to make it work. Lots of things on Stackoverflow are trivial, doesn't mean they shouldn't be asked or answered.